# Preview.app Signatures - how to unencrypt without old keychain

Tags: backup, preview, keychain

Old mac died. Have a new mac Mac Have all files from old Mac (did a backup before it died). Have been operating with new Mac for several months now.

Needed to use the signatures option in Preview & realized I never transferred them over from the old Mac's backup.

So I read this, [Transferring Preview app signatures in Lion](http://www.stuartcarnie.com/2011/08/transferring-preview-app-signatures-in.html), and was able to snag the `com.apple.Preview.signatures.plist` file.

But, tho I have the keychain file(s) in the backup, how can I extract just the one I need for this without screwing up my current keychain data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to ~/Library/Keychains on your new Mac and make a copy/backup of your actual `login.keychain` with <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
2. Copy the old `login.keychain` in /Users/old_user_name/Library/Keychains from the backup to your desktop and rename it to `loginold.keychain`
3. Open `Keychain Access.app` and choose File -> 'Add Keychain...' in the menu, navigate to your desktop and select `loginold.keychain`
4. Now you have a new entry in *Keychains* named `loginold`. Choose `loginold` in *Keychains* and `Passwords` in *Category*

   [image: screenshot]
5. Select the object `Preview Signature Privacy` and drag it to the keychain `login` in *Keychains*. You will be asked for a password. Enter the password for the old keychain (probably your old user password) and choose `Always Allow` or `Allow`. Now the object will be moved to your login keychain.
6. Choose `login` in *Keychains* and `Passwords` in *Category* and check if the new object `Preview Signature Privacy` is present there.
7. If everything is ok right click `loginold` in *Keychains* and choose `Delete keychain "loginold"`. If you choose `Delete Files and References` in the following dialog box the keychain `loginold` will be deleted from your desktop and in *Keychains*

   [image: screenshot2]
8. Quit `Keychain Access.app`
9. Test everything with Preview.app
10. If everything went well go to ~/Library/Keychains and delete the file `login copy.keychain` built for safety reasons in step 1.
11. If something went wrong, you might revert to your previous keychain by deleting `login.keychain` in ~/Library/Keychains and renaming `login copy.keychain` to `login.keychain`. Then i usually log out and in again or restart my Mac to be save.

Slightly alternative way if the object `Preview Signature Privacy` is already present in your keychain `login`:
Perform the steps 1-4 from above
5. Locate the `Preview Signature Privacy` in `loginold` in *Keychains* and `Passwords` in *Category* and double click to edit.
6. Click the Show password checkbox and enter the old user password
7. Now the password used to encrypt the signature images is visible. Copy & paste it into a text editor and save the file or paste it directly into the password field of `Preview Signature Privacy` in your keychain `login`.
**Any by Preview.app previously signed/protected object on your new Mac might be inaccessible then though.**
Continue with the steps 7-11 from above

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  never realized the keychain app was that flexible.