# Preview - add Signature by key command. Find Menu name

Tags: preview, shortcut, menu-bar

On the face of it, this seems an impossible task.
You can add a key command to any menu item, but first you need the precise wording for that item. This makes contextual menu items difficult, but not impossible, to add commands to.

A Signature in the menu, on the other hand, has no visible wording. It's a thumbnail image.
Therefore, it would appear that in order to add a key command, we must first find the name of that item… if it has one.

Does anyone have a method to discover that name, should it exist?

Comment: If you look at questions like https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/150325/73452 the signature is not a file itself but is stored in a keystore. You may want to check if it is still true for newer versions and if you can use this keystore for your menu binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Does anyone have a method to discover that name, should it exist?"

In **Preview** using **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**, the *properties* of a the *menu item* that is the *image* of the *signature* shows as: 
 `AXTitle <empty string>`

If you do not have **Xcode** installed, you can also get the *properties* of the target *menu item* in **Script Editor** with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below by changing `click ¬` to `return properties of ¬`, and on my system it returned `title:""` and `name:missing value` for those two particular *properties*.

---

### Alternate Solution

As any *keyboard shortcut* you'd assign has to be unique to the target *application*, why not just use an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* assigned that *keyboard shortcut* and use the following *example* **Automator**  *Quick Action/Service* to achieve the goal of being able to apply a *signature* in **Preview**:

Use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* configured as show in the image below.

I used **⌃⌥⌘S** for the *keyboard shortcut* assigned to it in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click ¬
        menu item 1 of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu item "Signature" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu item "Annotate" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Tools" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in as an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Replace the default *code* of the **Run AppleScript** *action* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

Localization of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* may be necessary for other languages/regional settings.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* as currently coded assumes only one *signature* exists in the *menu hierarchy*.  The `menu item 1 of` following `click ¬` can be changed to a different *value* as needed.

---

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hadn't thought of doing it that way. Have a nice bounty :)) [when it will let me]