# How to debug Services issues

Tags: macos, shortcut, services

I am trying to add a <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut for opening a terminal session in a given directory on macOS but for some reason after I put the shortcut in *Keyboard Shortcut* and then *Service*. When I press  a <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>, I get a new tab in Finder and not a shell.

Attempted to reset to defaults but that did not fix the issue.

How do I set up an automation so pressing those keys does an action inside terminal app on macOS?

[image: Here's a screen shot]

For reset I just click the Restore Defaults button.

Comment: Can you explain what “ Attempted to reset to defaults” looks like? We might also need a screen shot of how you are trying to add the shortcut to make sense of the work you’ve got into this. The intended results are clear so that’s super.

Comment: @bmike Thanks Mike, I added a screenshot.

Comment: Just some friendly, practical advice… Don’t override the [system keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) because it will cause issues like what you’re experiencing.  `Cmd-T` is predefined to open a new Finder Tab.

Comment: You *can* do it by changing the default New Tab command to something else - see [How do I add, change or remove a key command from a menu item?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464293/how-do-i-add-change-or-remove-a-key-command-from-a-menu-item) - but I agree it's unwise to try replacing what are essentially global key commands.

Comment: My question is how to fix the services which are clearly non functional.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea What says they're non-functional?  If you bind a non-system-reserved key sequence to it, does that work?  Several commenters have posted about trying to override a system keybind.

Comment: @MarcWilson tried multiple shortcuts none of them work, also on right click there is no services option in a folder in finder. So they don't work.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea You are rt-clicking IN a folder, or ON a folder? Services apply to an object.  If you don't even see the Services menu when rt-clicking ON a folder, you have a larger problem.

Comment: @MarcWilson IN a folder, ON a folder apparently is the intended way. this way even with keyboard shortcut to open terminal works. I just think it'd have been more intuitive to navigate inside a folder and then hit some keyboard shortcut to open a terminal there. Thanks.

Comment: You don't get 'Services' on right click, you get 'Quick Actions'… which, frankly,  is designed to confuse:\ Services are in the Finder Menu & do take key commands set in prefs… so long as they don't conflict with existing commands. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOMxR.png

Comment: @Tetsujin It's a poorly documented OS. What are those for at the top? I found for my particular use case to open a terminal in a specified terminal but what else is possible with services?

Comment: I honestly don't know how or why Apple differentiated. At one time in Automator you would make a Service. Now you make a Quick Action… but the key commands for it go in Services. The two seem inadequately defined. I think it's one of those things that got lost in the Jobs/Cook transition, like fullscreen & Spaces; broken & never fixed. Patched up with some half-hearted splitscreen & now Stage Manager:\